# How to use FieldValue ServerTimestamp in TypeScript data model?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using TypeScript to define the data models for my documents in Firebase. When the document is being created the `createdOn` field will be the server timestamp sentinal, but otherwise it is a date. For example...

```
export interface Post<MODE extends 'create' | 'read'> {
  comment: string;
  createdOn: MODE extends 'create' ? FieldValue : Date;
}
```

I don't know how to properly define and assign to the createdOn property. First, I'm not really sure which firebase module to load the FieldValue type from. The best I could do was this and this seems a bit hokey...

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
type FieldValue = firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue;
export const SERVER_TIMESTAMP = firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

And then when I use it, this is what happens...

```
// Fails when used within cloud function
// Detected an object of type "FieldValue" that doesn't match the
// expected instance (found in field "createdOn"). Please ensure 
/// that the Firestore types you are using are from the same NPM package.

post.createdOn = SERVER_TIMESTAMP;

// But this works within cloud function

post.createdOn = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Are the types of FieldValue different when called from within a cloud function and on the client? Can I simply import this type from some module that works from both cloud functions and client?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a known limitation confusing issue with the javascript SDKs.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4246

If you are creating an item in Firestore from an admin app you need to use a different "serverTimestamp" object than when creating one from a client app.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has quite a few products in their lineup so it's not too intuitive and this can cause confusion. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#expandable-8) you can view all of the products and you can view how to properly implement each library.

In your case it seems you're missing firestore which you can import using:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Then you are able to use the Field value like so:

```
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue) is more information on Field values.